# CircleCI Hold step

Tags: circleci, circleci-workflows

I'm trying to add a hold job into a workflow in CircleCI's config.yml file but I cannot make it work and I'm pretty sure it's a really simple error on my part (I just can't see it!).

When validating it with the CircleCI CLI locally running the following command

`circleci config validate`:

I get the following error

`Error: Job 'hold' requires 'build-and-test-service', which is the name of 0 other jobs in workflow 'build-deploy'`

This is the config.yml (note it's for a Serverless Framework application - not that that should make any difference)

```
version: 2.1
jobs:
  build-and-test-service:
    docker:
      - image: timbru31/java-node
    parameters:
      service_path:
        type: string
    steps:
      - checkout
      - serverless/setup:
          app-name: serverless-framework-orb
          org-name: circleci
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - dependencies-cache-{{ checksum "v2/shared/package-lock.json" }}-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}-{{ checksum "<< parameters.service_path >>/package-lock.json" }}
            - dependencies-cache
      - run:
          name: Install dependencies
          command: |
            npm install
            cd v2/shared
            npm install
            cd ../../<< parameters.service_path >>
            npm install
      - run:
          name: Test service
          command: |
            cd << parameters.service_path >>
            npm run test:ci
      - store_artifacts:
          path: << parameters.service_path >>/test-results/jest
          prefix: tests
      - store_artifacts:
          path: << parameters.service_path >>/coverage
          prefix: coverage
      - store_test_results:
          path: << parameters.service_path >>/test-results
  deploy:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:lts
    parameters:
      service_path:
        type: string
      stage_name:
        type: string
      region:
        type: string
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Deploy application
          command: |
            cd << parameters.service_path >>
            serverless deploy --verbose --stage << parameters.stage_name >> --region << parameters.region >>
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - node_modules
            - << parameters.service_path >>/node_modules
          key: dependencies-cache-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}-{{ checksum "<< parameters.service_path >>/package-lock.json" }}
orbs:
  serverless: circleci/serverless-framework@1.0.1
workflows:
  version: 2
  build-deploy:
    jobs:
      # non-master branches deploys to stage named by the branch
      - build-and-test-service:
          name: Build and test campaign
          service_path: v2/campaign
          filters:
            branches:
              only: develop
      - hold:
          name: hold
          type: approval
          requires:
            - build-and-test-service
      - deploy:
          service_path: v2/campaign
          stage_name: dev
          region: eu-west-2
          requires:
            - hold
```

It's obvious the error relates to the `hold` step (near the bottom of the config) not being able to find the `build-and-test-service` just above it but `build-and-test-service` does exist so am stumped at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone reading I figured out why it wasn't working.

Essentially I was using the incorrect property reference under the `requires` key:

```
workflows:
  version: 2
  build-deploy:
    jobs:
      # non-master branches deploys to stage named by the branch
      - build-and-test-service:
          name: Build and test campaign
          service_path: v2/campaign
          filters:
            branches:
              only: develop
      - hold:
          name: hold
          type: approval
          requires:
            - build-and-test-service
```

The correct property reference in this case should have been the `name` of the previous step, i.e. `Build and test campaign` so I just changed that name to `build-and-test-service`.

I found the CircleCI docs were not very clear on this but perhaps it was because their examples surrounding manual approvals stated the `requires` property should be pointing to the root key of the job such as `build-and-test-service`.

I suppose I should have been more vigilant in my error reading too, it did mention `name` there as well.